# How do I make the link in the back div clickable

Tags: css

When the div "flips", I'd like to be able to click the link, how can I achieve this?

Apparently I need to write some more text or it won't let me post this question, who's going for a beer later?

CSS:

```
.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000;
}

.flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 320px;
    height: 200px;
}

.flipper {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}

.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.front {
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: red;
}

.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    background-color: green;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front">
            <!-- front content -->
            Front
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <!-- back content -->
            <a href="http://www.google.com">Click me</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iwasdavid/1qv7bLpo/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add following to your code. The addition of the `translateZ` makes it clickable

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/richasingh/1qv7bLpo/2/)**

```
.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(1px);
    background-color: green;

}
```

Comment: This works perfectly and I will accept it as soon as I can. Do you know why the translateZ(1px) is needed?

Comment: Glad to have helped. :) Here is link why it is needed https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=54371.

Comment: Leaving for the day, incase if you have further doubt will be glad to help you tomorow. :)